gamahucher dans le Wiktionnaire
Bonjour,
J'ai consulté le mot gamahucher dans le Wiktionnaire (https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gamahucher), où j'ai été particulièrement impressionné par la richesse de la description et des exemples dans ce dictionnaire en ligne. L’entrée de ce mot dans le Wiktionnaire est accompagnée de cinq exemples détaillés.
En effet, ce terme argotique, qui signifie exciter une zone érogène avec la langue, est souvent absent ou traité de manière très succincte dans de nombreux dictionnaires renommés tels que le TLFi, le Grand Robert, le Grand Larousse, et le FEW. J'ai également consulté plusieurs dictionnaires d’argot dans la bibliothèque et, bien qu'ils contiennent le mot gamahucher, leurs descriptions restent également concises, ne dépassant guère dix lignes. La seule exception est Bob, un dictionnaire d'argot en ligne (https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/26536). Nous avons remarqué que ce dictionnaire a recueilli plus de 10 exemples détaillés d'utilisation.
Ma question porte sur les exemples cités dans le Wiktionnaire. Tous ceux du Wiktionnaire sont tirés d'auteurs reconnus. Comment ces exemples ont-ils été collectés ?
Je ne pense pas que le Wiktionnaire ait été rédigé en se référant à Bob, car aucun des exemples n'est identique à ceux que l'on trouve dans Bob.
En particulier, le premier exemple tiré d'une remarque de Baudelaire est bien intéressant :
Pardon, je suis en retard, je viens de gamahucher ma mère. — (Charles Baudelaire, rapporté par les frères Goncourt dans leur Journal du 11 avril 1863)
J'ai vérifié si cet exemple figurait dans un autre dictionnaire, mais je ne l'ai pas trouvé, bien que je l'aie découvert cité dans un article de Robert Kopp, spécialiste de Baudelaire. J'en suis venu à penser que le Wiktionnaire pourrait surpasser de nombreux dictionnaires de référence et d'argot existants (à l'exception de Bob). En tout cas, concernant l'entrée du mot "gamahucher", le Wiktionnaire semble offrir la description bien étonnante. Bien entendu, les dictionnaires imprimés sont limités par le nombre de pages.
Ainsi, je me suis interrogé sur la méthode utilisée pour rassembler ces citations. Comment ces citations ont-elles été trouvées ? Existe-t-il un dictionnaire détaillé de termes argotiques dont je ne suis pas au courant ? (J'ai déjà consulté de nombreux dictionnaires dans Lexilogos https://www.lexilogos.com/argot.htm )   Ou bien l'entrée gamahucher du Wiktionnaire a-t-elle été rédigée par un contributeur particulièrement instruit, qui a rassemblé à lui seul ces beaux exemples d'utilisation Sans se référer à d'autres dictionnaires ?
En tout état de cause, la manière dont ces citations ont été trouvées est remarquable. Comment ces citations ont-elles été recueillies ? L’éditeur de l’article gamahucher a-t-il consulté quelque dictionnaire que je ne connais pas ? Il est à noter que la citation la plus intéressante des frères Goncourt sur la parole de Baudelaire n'a été trouvée dans aucun des dictionnaires consultés.
Je souhaiterais connaître votre avis à ce sujet. Par ailleurs, le Wiktionnaire est-il un des meilleurs dictionnaires pour l'argot ? Et comment puis-je trouver ces citations détaillées et littéraires ?
Je vous remercie par avance.

Il n'est besoin d'aucun dictionnaire pour connaître le mot, il suffit de vivre à proximité d'une université: "Du dieu Bacchus quand, accablé d'ivresse / [...] /À ta vertu nous rendons tous hommage: / Gamahuchons, c'est le plaisir des dieux!" http://www.chansons-paillardes.net/chansons_paillardes/Breviaire-paillardes/Les_Paroles/PlaisirDesDieux.html ; quant à la source des exemples, Sade et Apollinaire sont des célébrités du roman pornographique.

Il existe de très nombreux dictionnaires d'argot et dictionnaires de citations papier, qui comporte le mot. Les contributeurs au Wiktionnaire (et à Wikipedia) se contentent rarement de ce qu'ils trouvent sur internet et les articles sont complétés au fur et à mesure de leurs lectures des oeuvres originales (et de la presse)  par différents contributeurs. On voit dans l'historique de l'article que les citations ont été introduites par au moins deux contributeurs (je dis au moins, j'ai vérifié très vite). Plus on lit, plus on a de références...

I’m voting to close this question because it is about how a dictionary works and not about the language itself.

Il est certain que quand on écrit un article Baudelaire et les Goncourt on a non seulement lu tout Baudelaire mais aussi ce qu'en ont dit les frères Goncourt ! Les manuscrits des Frères Goncourt sont accessibles à tous (pour la citation en question à la BNF, et sur Gallica).

I’m voting to close this question because it's basically "which French slang resources did I miss", not about the French language itself.

Je vous remercie pour vos messages.
En effet, ma question ne porte pas sur la langue française elle-même, mais sur les dictionnaires français. Je m'excuse pour le fait que la question posée n'était pas appropriée.
Je voudrais ajouter un point personnel : J'ai été surpris de constater que le Wiktionnaire est un excellent dictionnaire, meilleur que de nombreux dictionnaires d'argot existants et que les dictionnaires les plus prestigieux, que j’avais déjà mentionnés.

J'apprends le français comme langue étrangère et je n'ai souvent consulté que des dictionnaires prestigieux, fréquemment mentionnés dans les bibliographies. Jusqu'à présent, je n'avais pas pris connaissance des avantages du Wiktionnaire.

Il y a de tout dans le Wiktionnaire, du bon et parfois des erreurs. Donc à prendre avec précaution. Par exemple je ne dirais pas que gamahucher est « vulgaire ». C'est vieilli et littéraire, peu connu (et encore moins employé de nos jours), c'est un mot qui fait partie de la littérature érotique des 18e et 19e siècles. Et d'après le Dictionnaire Historique en langue française (Édition Le Robert)  en langue je ne me risquerais à donner une étymologie  – Excellent français pour un non francophone !

Le verbe gamahucher se trouve 17 fois dans le Dictionnaire érotique moderne (2e éd. rev., corr... enrichie de nombreuses citations) d'Alfred Delvau publié en 1864.

Je vous remercie de vos réponses précieuses.Merci également de m’avoir informé du Robert historique et du dictionnaire Delvau.

Par la suite, J'ai modifié mes méthodes de recherche, pensant que je pourrais peut-être trouver moi-même de beaux exemples comme ceux dans le Wiktionnaire. Quand j'ai recherché cette chaîne de caractères (qui n'est jamais élégante !) sur Google, j'ai obtenu un assez grand nombre de résultats pour "gamahucher" sur Wikisource. Ou bien, en supprimant seulement la première partie de cette chaîne qui spécifie Wikisource et en effectuant une recherche sur Google Livres, j'ai également obtenu de nombreux résultats.

site:fr.wikisource.org gamahucher OR gamahuche OR gamahuches OR gamahuchons OR gamahuchez OR gamahuchent OR gamahuché OR gamahuchais OR gamahuchait OR gamahuchions OR gamahuchiez OR gamahuchaient OR gamahucherai OR gamahucheras OR gamahuchera OR gamahucherons OR gamahucherez OR gamahucheront OR gamahucherais OR gamahucherait OR gamahucherions OR gamahucheriez OR gamahucheraient OR gamahucha OR gamahuchai OR gamahuchas OR gamahuchèrent

Enfin, il semble que l'exemple de Baudelaire ne soit pas facile à trouver sur Internet. Quel génie qu’un éditeur de l'article gamahucher dans le Wiktionnaire ! A-t-il lu l'article de Robert Kopp ? !
Je vous remercie finalement d'avoir pris le temps de répondre à mes questions !
